# Is it safe to use ansible's package module to upgrade all packages?

Tags: ansible

I have a numer of ansible playbooks I use to perform certain actions on Debian and CentOS VMs. Until now, when I needed to handle packages I would use ansible modules [apt](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/apt_module.html) and [yum](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/yum_module.html). Consequently, I had to check which OS was installed and then use the correct ansible module.

However, I've recently learned there's a module called [package](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/package_module.html) which somehow unifies package managers, reducing playbook's complexity, so I'm now trying to use this module only.

One of the operations I want to perform is to update all packages. The problem is that [ansible's documentation](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/package_module.html) doesn't say how to do this using *package*. It does say, however, how to do it with *apt* and *yum*: the first one uses and upgrade operation and the latter suggests writing something like:

```
yum: name=* state=latest
```

For this reason I thought I could use *package* to do the following:

```
package: name=* state=latest
```

When I ran this playbook I didn't come across any error but this isn't documented anywhere and *apt* and *yum* don't work exactly the same way. So my question is: is the command above a safe one as in does it actually do what I want it to do?

Thanks in advance!

EDIT:

I have found out that using `package: name=* state=latest` will try to install or update all available packages instead of just updating installed ones. Therefore this isn't a valid solution for me. Alternatively, I can keep using *yum* and *apt* for this particular action, but I do wonder why is it not possible to do this using *package*, or if I'm missing something.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well after further testing I can now answer the question by myself, and the answer is no. Using `package: name=* state=latest` on a Debian machine will try to install or update every package available in the repositories, so it can't be used as a replacement for an `apt-get upgrade`.

Answer (score -1):

From the docs below i think its clear that the use you are describing can be considered safe.

From [package](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/package_module.html) documentation:

> This module actually calls the pertinent package modules for each system (apt, yum, etc).

So whatever you pass to it should be supported by the underlined packagers yum or apt.

From [apt](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/apt_module.html) documentation:

> Name wildcards (fnmatch) like apt* and version wildcards like foo=1.0* are also supported.

From [yum->name](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/yum_module.html) documentation:

> When using state=latest, this can be '*' which means run: yum -y update.

EDIT: After @Xavier Alvarez testing the `apt: name=* state=latest` will install **all packages in repo**.

Comment: I think that that comment related to apt doesn't necessarily imply that using just a wildcard will upgrade all packages, specially because there's a specific upgrade flag for that module. So I wonder if just using a wildcard would install or upgrade *all* packages instead of just upgrading the ones that are already installed.

Comment: The reason i believe the apt wildcard works for all packages is the [fnmatch](https://docs.python.org/2/library/fnmatch.html) that is mentioned in docs, and supports that kind of wildcard as you can see in its docs.

Comment: I have just tested it and it doesn't work the way I want. If I use `package: name=* state=latest` in a Debian machine it will try to install *all* packages available in the repositories. What I want is to update those packages that are already installed. I think the best will be to use **apt** and **yum** modules at this step.

Comment: Hmm with a second look make sense the behavior of apt since the asterisk matching everything, nice edit in order not to misguide anyone else.